# What are the different operators like =,<,>,% etc. called (named) in Russian

Tags: математика

I made a Google search, but couldn't find any answer. I'd like to know the names of the operators

> +, -, x, /, =, <, >, %, {, }, (, ), :, &, etc.

Also I would appreciate links pointing to such symbols if there are any.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is a page on wikipedia dedicated to mathematical symbols:

- [Таблица математических символов](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85_%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2) (List of mathematical symbols)

Also there is a category:

- [Знаки препинания](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F:%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) (punctuation symbols)

For example on the [main page](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) you can find a sidebar with links to pretty much all of the symbols from your question.

**UPDATE**: Symbols mentioned in original question:

`+` - `плюс`, `знак сложения`. Related operation: `сложение` (addition).
`-` - `минус`,`знак вычитания`. Related operation: `вычитание` (subtraction). 
`x`,`*` - `знак умножения`. Related operation: `умножение` (multiplication). 
    More specific:
      `x` - `крестик` (applicable to symbol only not to the
mathematical operation itself)
      `*` - `звёздочка` (symbol only);
`/`,`:` - `знак деления`. Related operation: `деление`(division).
    More specific:
      `/` - `косая черта` (symbol only);
      `÷` - `обелюс` (symbol only);
      `:` - `двоеточие` (symbol only);

`=` - `знак равенства`. Related operations: `равенство`(equality), `присвоение`(assignment).
`≡` - `знак тождественности`. Related operation: `сравнение по модулю`(congruence relation, as in modular arithmetic)
`<` - `меньше` (literally `less`)
`>` - `больше` (literally `greater`)
`%` - `знак процента`, `процент`
`()` - `скобки`, `круглые скоки`
`(` - `открывающая скобка`
`)` - `закрывающая скобка`
`{}` - `фигурные скобки`
`<>` - `угловые скобки`
`[]` - `квадратные скобки`
`&` - `амперсанд` (symbol only). Operation: `логическое И`,`И` (logic AND),`побитовое И`(bitwise AND)
`.` - `точка` (symbol only, literally `point`). Also, `десятичная точка` (decimal point), `десятичный разделитель` (decimal separator)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time,I actually hoped to find it in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_alphabet . but seems it is not there.

Comment: I edited the translation of сравнение since its technical meaning in math would be called "congruence" (as in 8 = 2 mod 3), even though its everyday meaning translates as "comparison".

Comment: @Kcd, thanks for your edit. But in most of the cases I faced modular arithmetic russian texts tended to use ≡ (знак тождественности) for this (like `b ≡ r mod n`). I understand your point, though. Comparison really sounds wrong. Maybe I should just replace it with равенство (equality)

Comment: On daily basis I mostly deal with programming, not math. So `=` for me mostly mean assignment or comparison.

Comment: @defaultlocale: I agree ≡ should be used instead of = in modular arithmetic, but I don't know how to produce ≡ directly from my keyboard. In retrospect I could have just cut and pasted it from some webpage, just as I have done now with the ≡ that you put in your comment.

Comment: Yes it's quite hard to enter it from keyboard. Actually I first found the symbol and it's unicode value. There are OS and program dependent hacks that allow to enter unicode directly from keyboards.

Comment: @DmitryAlexandrov yes, the usage of word `обелюс` is probably limited to typography literature. But I've seen this sign being used for division by junior school math textbooks and some calculators.

Comment: I never heard word *обелюс* in Russian for `÷` except as an answer to the question like ‘How this character per se may be called?’ Since it’s used in electrical engineering as range sing, e. g. *10÷15 mA*, and never for division it may be called simply *знак диапазона* or *тире* (dash) if you do not want to pay attention to the dots above and below.

Comment: Sorry, I’ve accidentally post unfinished comment and noticed it when time limit for edition was exceed, so I’ve deleted it and post it again. Now order of comments is messed up a little.

Comment: @defaultlocale Yes, `÷` is certainly used on most calculator’s keyboards as division sign. I’ve omitted this fact as unrelated to Russian language.

Comment: @defaultlocale So the Western tradition came to our junior schools, if `÷` is in use there nowadays. When I was a junior pupil we never used it. We had another highly unusual in real life division sign – a colon `:`.

Comment: Also `<` and `>` can be used not as ‘less-than’ and ‘greater-than’ signs but as brackets (like in e-mail address, e. g. `Dmitry Alexandrov <321942@gmail.com>`), then they should be called *угловые скобки*.

Comment: @DmitryAlexandrov I recall a story from my university days. Math analysis professor noticed that several students used a colon for division. He then said that, back in his school days in Soviet Union, pupils were required by math teacher to actually draw the line between dots. So, now I'm a bit confused whether it's the Western tradition. P.S. I've made a couple of updates to my answer and turned it into community wiki. Feel free to improve it.

Comment: the star `*` is normally pronounced as "умножить на" in exact this form.